# Handle all exceptions and display custom error page instead of default framework error page

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-1.x

I am using **Play!Framework 1.2.5**. I want to handle all errors in play framework in a customized way. For example if there is route error I would like to display an appropriate error message instead of showing the whole route file. Likewise for other errors, I would like to display my own error page. How to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can define your own error page by creating new sub-package named `errors` on `views` package. In this sub-package, you can create template file for your customized error page using the **error code** name such as:

1. `404.html` for **Not Found Error** page
2. `403.html` for **Forbidden Error** page
3. `500.html` for **Internal Server Error** page
4. etc...

Don't worry for the default route not found error page, it's only shown on development mode for helping development phase. While in production mode, this error page (the default framework error page) will not be displayed.

**-- UPDATE**

This `@Catch` annotation maybe useful for handling other type of exception. It act as interceptor for action in your controller, and will handle exception if exception occur while doing some action. Note that this annotation only works in **Controller** class.

Please check the documentation [here](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.5/controllers#catch) for further read.

Answer (score 2):

We needed a bit more control than what @iwawiwi mentioned to figure out what database constraint message was thrown by the database. That was solved by using a method with a `@Catch` annotation like this in a `Controller` class:

```
@Catch(value=PersistenceException.class)
public static void handleException(PersistenceException exception) {
    ..
}
```

I hadn't heard of that annotation before and this has worked pretty good in my situation.

For missing routes we've added a bit in this `Controller` as well:

```
@Catch(value=ActionNotFoundException.class)
public static void catchRouteNotFound(ActionNotFoundException exception) {
    String referer = session.get("referer");

    Logger.error("ActionNotFoundException, referer: %s", referer);
    Logger.error("Exception: %s", exception);
}
```

This way we can find out about missing routes / wrong links in the application.

Comment: +1 Wow, that's cool. I just aware for that annotation power, .. ;) But, there is maybe issue when we want to place `@Catch` interceptor at some action that marked by interceptor `@Before` in controller. Because they two act as interceptor. But, It is not so much problem just don't mark the action with `@Catch`, just handle inside the method.. Isn't it?

Comment: I don't think it matters to be honest. As far as I know, Play looks around in your Controllers for an Exception handler for the exception thrown. I don't think that it matters if it's thrown in a `@Before` annotated method or not. I think you can easily try that by throwing your own CustomException in an @Before method and try catch it.